# Align items with the same starting point

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

My html looks like that:

```
<div class="text-center"> (bootstrap class)
  <p>Username</p>
  <p>Name:</p>
  <p>Last name:</p>
  <p>Email:</p>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kgmzr5tc/1/)

I am trying to center align items, but I need them to start at the same point:

[desired look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zbSI.png)

Any chance to achieve that using bootstrap?

Comment: The html does not match the output. Please add the full markup, and post a live example/codepen if possible.

Comment: Hi and welcome. To get the best reply you would have to add more html and css to it. What do you got so far.

Comment: @SeanDoherty  https://jsfiddle.net/kgmzr5tc/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div style="display:flex; justify-content:center;">
 <div>
  <p>Username:</p>
  <p>Name:</p>
  <p>Last name:</p>
  <p>Email:</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

You need to take of the `.text-center`, an extra wrapper and then flex-center on the external wrapper. The flex centers the extra wrapper we put in, and the default align for that is left.

Comment: I want them in the middle